# C# windows phone 7: Animating ListBoxItems created via DataTemplate

Tags: c#, windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have this xaml:

```
<ListBox Margin="12,0,0,0" Height="50" FontSize="30" Name="resultListBox">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <toolkit:WrapPanel Margin="0,0,24,0" Background="{Binding Path=background}" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,12,0" Width="49" Text="{Binding Path=line}" />
        <TextBlock Width="261" Text="{Binding Path=destination}" />
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,12,0" Width="49" Text="{Binding Path=next}" />
        <TextBlock  Width="49" Text="{Binding Path=nextNext}" />
        <toolkit:WrapPanel.Projection>
          <PlaneProjection CenterOfRotationY="0.5" x:Name="WrapPanelPP{Binding Path=ID}" RotationX="-90" />
        </toolkit:WrapPanel.Projection>
      </toolkit:WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

And i would like to animate the plane projection of each item. What do do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways you can handle this.

1. Use Expression Blend to create storyboards and call the storyboards on proper trigger.
   or
2. In code behind you can create a instance of Storyboard and target the "(UIElement.Projection).(RotationX)" property on the item.

> 

Comment: well yes but do i access the plane projection propery of my wrappanel in this case?